# Is calling wait() on a std::future multiple times and from multiple threads safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to determine when I can safely call `wait()` on `std::future` and `std::shared_future`. I never call `get()` on the `future`, and the `future` is set ready from a call to its corresponding promise's `set_value()` method.

I want to wait on this `future` (using `wait()`, `wait_for()`, `wait_until()`) from multiple threads. I also want calls to `wait()` after `promise::set_value()` has been called to return immediately.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/wait/

> Calling this member function on a future object that is not valid, produces undefined behavior

Getting a `future` from a `promise` starts it off with `valid()==true`. As far as I can see only `future::get()` sets `valid()` back to false. Is this assumption correct? Can I call the `wait()` family of functions as often as I want? Will calls to `wait()` after the promise's value has been set return immediately? Can I call them from multiple threads?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Getting a future from a promise starts it off with valid()==true. As far as I can see only future::get() sets valid() back to false. Is this assumption correct?

It can also become invalid by move-assigning an invalid future to it, or by moving the future so its shared state transfers to a different object. It can't become invalid just by waiting though.

> Can I call the wait() family of functions as often as I want?

Yes.

> Will calls to wait() after the promise's value has been set return immediately?

Yes (it might involve locking a mutex or spinlock to check if the state is ready, then returning, so might involve a small wait to acquire the lock)

> Can I call them from multiple threads?

Yes.

`wait()` is a const member function, so the library is required to ensure it can be called on a single future object from multiple threads without any user-provided synchronisation.

Comment: I am not sure that simply making a function `const` guarantees it is *thread safe*. Does the spec mention this is a requirement?

Comment: I don't like using the word "thread safe" because it means different things to different people. 17.6.5.9 [res.on.data.races] says that the standard library must ensure that calling (only) `const` member functions on a single object does not introduce data races. If the object has  state shared with other objects (as `future` does) then the library must provide its own synchronisation to prevent races. This doesn't mean simply adding `const` is magic pixie dust that provides thread safety, it means the library is sometimes required to do extra work to provide a guarantee for `const` functions.

Comment: The simple fact that `wait()` is `const` is just a guarantee that the function will not modify the state of the object.  However it is not by istelf a gurantee that result is consistent/syncrhonized with changes made by other threads.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Looking at **17.6.5.9** it states that the requirements do *not* need to be met where the standard specifies otherwise. It also goes on to state that *const* functions must *synchronize* any objects shared across threads.

However **30.6.6** states that member functions of `std::future` do **not** *synchronize* with other threads. Thus it seems to me that member functions of `std::future` are an *exception* to the general rules specified in **17.6.5.9**. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Calls to `promise::set_value()` synchronize with calls to `future::wait()` that detect the state is ready (30.6.4 [futures.state] p9), what other synchronisation is needed for the OP's question? It doesn't matter if calls to `wait()` in different threads synchronize with each other, just that they don't introduce data races, and [res.on.data.races] says they don't. It would be absurd for `std::future` to offer _weaker_ guarantees regarding data races than `std::string`

Comment: The note in 30.6.6 p2 is a note, so non-normative, so it cannot overrule the requirements in 17.6.5.9 -- all it is saying is that futures don't offer _stronger_ guarantees than 17.6.5.9 (which is worth noting because some people might reasonably expect futures to do so), it's not saying it offers weaker guarantees.

Comment: Not knowing how `std::future::wait()` is implemented, I am not sure we can know if it needs synchronization to avoid data races or not, given that the standard has explicitly stated that it does not provide synchronization and **[res.on.data.races]** says there are exceptions. After all why would they provide such a note **3.6.6.2** when **[res.on.data.races]** says they *must* be synchronized? What else is that note telling us?

Comment: I just answered that. Read my previous comment. A non-normative note **cannot** define an exception to normative requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing a single `future` from multiple threads might lead to data race and undefined behaviour if at least one of them could perform a `get()` and no proper synchronisation would avoid such a situation.

Hence, if you need to access a `future` from multiple threads, you should better consider `shared_future`: [*"They also allow the value in the shared state to be retrieved multiple times once ready."*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/shared_future/) They are thread safe as long as each thread accesses to the shared future using its own `shared_future` object.

***Remark:*** My answer assumes that at some time a get() could occur, as the promise was not explicitely mentioned to be `promise<void>`

Comment: Accessing the result in multiple threads conflicts and can lead to a data race, but just waiting for the shared state to become ready does not. The OP clearly says "I never call get() on the future," so is never accessing the result.

Comment: And even though it's irrelevant to this question, your second paragraph could be misunderstood to imply more "thread safety" than is actually guaranteed. Accesses to the result still conflict even if you access it through distinct `shared_future` objects ([futures.state] p11).

Comment: I agree that the simple access to wait() is not the problem. The problem is the succession of accesses, as the calls to member functions of one perticular future instance are not guaranteed to be synchronized (see "C++ Concurrency in action", waiting from multiple threads, p.55).

Comment: I think p.85 (not 55!) is talking about calls to `get()` (which is non-`const`) but I agree it's not entirely clear, I'll raise that with @AnthonyWilliams. The entire standard library is required to avoid data races if you call `const` member functions on a single object from multiple threads, `future::wait()` is no exception.

Comment: Yes, thanks: 85 and not 55 !  I should switch the light on as I get older ;-) I would be very interested in the C++ standard quote that confirms your guarantee about atomicity of const member function.

Comment: I didn't say atomicity! I wish people would stop trying to put the words "thread safety" or "atomicity" into my mouth! The reference you want is 17.6.5.9 [res.on.data.races], paragraphs 4 and 7 in particular. It does **not** say calls to const members must be atomic, it says they must not introduce data races.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I wasn't aware of such high guarantees in the lib.  However the fact that the const member function does not race does not ensure that it's sequentially consistent accross several threads.  I've understood that the overcoming of this design issue was prime readon why the shared_future were created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65429/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-christophe).

Comment: @JonathanWakely is right: I was thinking about concurrent calls to `get()`, `swap()`, assignment, etc. Concurrent calls to `const` member functions of `std::future` (such as `wait()`) do not themselves introduce any data races, since they are covered by 17.6.5.9.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Thanks for this explanation. I'll edit my answer accordingly. But am I right about the following:  as soon as there is one concurent get() race amy occur, and there is an UB unless shared_future is used ?

Comment: Yes, that's true for any non-const functions unless the standard says otherwise. But that's irrelevant here because the OP is only calling `wait()`, you're assumption that there is a call to `get()` is wrong because the OP says **"I never call `get()` on the `future`"**. How many times do I have to point that out?